# random images with background: linking to a random image php script - simpler and better way

Tags: php, variables

I know there has to be a better way to do this.

Currently I have a php script which will generate a random image from a certain directory when called.

I have div's calling the `background.php` file in the stylesheet under the div's background setting

```css
background:url(randomimagescript.php);
```

There are a lot of little div's on this page right now, all calling separate random image php scripts... is there a way I could use a variable when calling the file, so I can just use one script? I still need to have good styling control over the image, so i'm not sure if there is a better option than calling the script as a background image for a div.

If anyone has any ideas, let me know!

Comment: Could you tell us exactly _how_ you are choosing which file to take? as in, which function?

Comment: so i have a seperate php file for ever directory currently 

    $folder = 'galleries/couples/thumbs/';

which is getting a bit tedious with 10-15 directories... thinking it'd be possible to call the php file with a var, being the directory, but not sure if that's even possible since i'm using the script in a div's background setting haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (it might not be optimal):

```
background:url("randomimagescript.php?folder=myfolder");
```

and in randomimagescript.php:

```
<?php
    $folder = @_$REQUEST['folder'];
    $url = "galleries/$folder/thumbs/image.jpg";  // ie, compose image
    http_redirect($url);  // go and find the image.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a little crazy, but you could actually make your stylesheet be generated by PHP, and just fill in the blank, so to speak.

```
background:url(<? echo pickRandomImage(); ?>)
```

Comment: ahha. is there any downside to calling a php file as a stylesheet instead of a css? Might as well just embed the function into the stylesheet I suppose

Answer (score 0):

set the background for all divs once on the page using jquery

```
var image = <?echo randomimagescript.php?>

 $("div").css('background', 'url('+ image+ ')');
```